# How can i smoothen my swipe in upwards direction?

Tags: android, android-gesture

I have been working for smoothing my upward swipe but was unable understand how to get it done. I am actually not clear with the terms/words of the code given as the answer to the previous questions on stack overflow.
Any help would be appreciated. Please answer with an code + explanation of it. Thanking to replies in advance.

I have the following code with swipe up but its not smooth:

```
SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        String TAG = "TAG";
        float sensitvity = 70;
        if (upflag == true) {
            if ((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Up Left performed");
                return false;
            } else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Up Right performed");
                return false;
            }

            if (e1.getY() >= e2.getY() - 100) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Up swipe performed");
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(
                        "com.teneleven", MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (preferences.contains("storyid") && upflag == true) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                            TradingRefrenceActivity.class);
                    ((AppController) getApplicationContext())
                            .setRefDate(mtv_Date.getText().toString());
                    bundle.putString("news_id",
                            preferences.getString("storyid", ""));
                    bundle.putString("category",
                            preferences.getString("story_category", ""));
                    bundle.putString("colorcode",
                            preferences.getString("story_colorcode", ""));
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
                    threadFlag = false;
                    stopHandler();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in,
                            R.anim.push_up_out);

                    return true;
                }

                // if ((e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > sensitvity) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "Up swipe performed");
                // SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(
                // "com.teneleven", MODE_PRIVATE);
                // if (preferences.contains("storyid")) {
                // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                // Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                // TradingRefrenceActivity.class);
                // bundle.putString("news_id",
                // preferences.getString("storyid", ""));
                // bundle.putString("category",
                // preferences.getString("story_category", ""));
                // bundle.putString("slug",
                // preferences.getString("category_slug", ""));
                // i.putExtras(bundle);
                // startActivity(i);
                //
                // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in,
                // R.anim.push_up_out);
                // return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                // }

            } else if ((e2.getY() - e1.getY()) > sensitvity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Down swipe performed");
                return false;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "None swipe performed");
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

Comment: For achieving vertical viewpager! please use "com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1" this Library.

https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager use this link.

Comment: @praneeth kumar do i have to import it in my code or download the library? If to import guide me what to write and if to download please provide me a direct link to download coz i'm not able to understand what to download from above given link and also do guide to include it in my code.

Comment: your this help would be very much helpful @praneeth kumar.

Comment: You have to import this as a Library using Gradel, Include this library in gradel dependencies, and build  the project(sync).

Comment: @praneeth kumar still not understood where to find a gradle in eclipse. please give path....!:[]

Comment: IT woks for Android studio! don't know about eclips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code you can change velocity ,min and max distance to

1) MainSwipe.class

```
public class MainSwipe extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleGestureListener{

    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipe_screen);
        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class

        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {

        switch (direction) {
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :
                Log.e("UP","UP");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        Log.e("Doubletab","Doubletab");
    }
}
```

2) SimpleGestureFilter

```
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
    public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
    public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
    public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

    public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
    public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
    public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

    private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
    private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
    private int swipe_Max_Distance = 500;
    private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

    private int mode             = MODE_DYNAMIC;
    private boolean running      = true;
    private boolean tapIndicator = false;

    private Activity context;
    private GestureDetector detector;
    private SimpleGestureListener listener;

    public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

        this.context = context;
        this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        this.listener = sgl;
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        if(!this.running)
            return;

        boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            else if (result)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            else if(this.tapIndicator){
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                this.tapIndicator = false;
            }

        }
        //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
    }

    public void setMode(int m){
        this.mode = m;
    }

    public int getMode(){
        return this.mode;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean status){
        this.running = status;
    }

    public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
        this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
        this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
        this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
        return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
        return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
        return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {

        final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
        final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

        if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
            return false;

        velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

        if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
            if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

            result = true;
        }
        else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
            if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        this.tapIndicator = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
        this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

        if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
            arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.
            this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

3) Interface SimpleGestureListener

```
public interface SimpleGestureListener {
    void onSwipe(int direction);
    void onDoubleTap();
}
```

Comment: that mean i have to just change the velocity to smoothen my swipe??

Comment: whose velocity it is my swipe velocity or slide transition velocity?

Comment: @Shubham Nangalia yes , and its swipe velocity